# Site on https starts working only after refreshing page on http page

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, iis, windows-server-2016

I have a SharePoint server with `sp` name which I can access by `http://sp`.

I've

1. added this server to some domain and could access it by `http://sp.domain.local`;
2. created and added certificate to this server, so I could access it by `https://sp.domain.local` and by `https://sp`;
3. allowed access to it from Internet by https://external.domain.com

Issue:

When I try to access the server by `http://sp.domain.local`, `https://sp.domain.local`, `https://external.domain.com` after some time, for example, in a day, it allows me to be logged in, but does not display the Documents list content and search does not work.

When I refresh `http://sp` page, then `Documents` List content becomes visible and search starts to work here on http and https protocols and with sp.domain.local and external.domain.com names.

Question:

Which settings on SP or IIS side could be the cause of such behavior?

Images:

[image]
[image]

After accessing site through `http://sp`, previous links start working
[image]

Comment: Did you extend the web app the the "https://external.domain.com" or are you just using alternative access mappings?

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan Sorry, I don't know what means extend. I just access it using alternative domain names.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configure Sharepoint Warmup script.
This will be a workaround but not a solution.

Can you find any information related to your issue in ULS logs when you access all these sites?
Have you configured Alternate access mappings?

Comment: After alternate access mappings applied, Documents content became visible, but search does not work in this location.

Comment: Search will work only on default url. It will not give results of other added url..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AAM, here is a simple tutorial you could have a look to check if there is any issue with the configuration.

[SHAREPOINT 2016: HOW TO IMPLEMENT ALTERNATE ACCESS MAPPING](https://howtodowithsharepoint.wordpress.com/2018/01/26/sharepoint-2016-how-to-implement-alternate-access-mapping/)